# writing the console output to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the console output to be written into a file,
how do you redirect the console outut to
a file 'c1.txt'?
plz help.
This is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob
import re
import os

def removegarbage(text):
    # Replace one or more non-word (non-alphanumeric) chars with a space
    text = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text)
    text = text.lower()
    return text

topwords = 100
folderpath = 'path/to/directory'
counter = Counter()
for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath, '*.txt')):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as filehandle:
        counter.update( removegarbage(filehandle.read()).split() )

for word, count in counter.most_common(topwords):
    print ('{}: {}'.format(count, word))
```

Comment: Do you have output when printing straight to console? Is c1.txt file created after you run the program?

Comment: Have a look here:
[Stackoverflow - Write stdout to file in Python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python

I guess this is what you're searching

Comment: yes, c1.txt is created after running the program

Comment: no..it doesn't seem to work out,i tried this:import sys
sys.stdout = open('c1.txt', 'w')
print 'test'

Comment: Try `open('c1.txt', 'a')`.

Comment: @user2464521 did you check the answer below?